# SELECT on column value = X but if no rows available then any column value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

In MSSQL 2016 enterprise edition I have a table column which can contain an int. I'd like to query for 1000 rows where this column equal X, but if no rows then column may contain any value.

Eg:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 COLS FROM TABLE WHERE  <COL = 4 OR IF NO ROWS THEN COL = ANY VALUE>
```

How do I write the logic within < and >

Comment: What you want to obtain if only 600 records have `col=X`? 600 records with `X` only? or 600 with `X` and 400 with `any`?

Comment: Please include some sample data and expected output. Limit your example to 10 rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>`DECLARE @id int=4 
    SELECT TOP 1000 COLS FROM TABLE WHERE  col=COALESCE(@id,col)`</strike>

<strike>if the @id is null then it will retrieve top 1000 rows</strike>

OR

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM  FROM TABLE WHERE  col=4)
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1000 COLS FROM TABLE WHERE  col=4
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
SELECT TOP 1000 COLS FROM TABLE
END
```

OR

**EDIT 1:**
As stated by laughing vergil the first one will fail if there is no records in with col=4 and won't return any rows.
if the OP needs always 1000 rows as result set

```
SELECT TOP 1000 cols from (
SELECT TOP (1000) COLS FROM TABLE WHERE col=4
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP (1000) COLS from TABLE
)
ORDER BY case when col=4 then 0 else 1 end
```

This have a downside it always queries 1000 rows twice!. I think Akina answer is a good one. Also another caveat of this is the order the inner select is done which will select random 1000 rows.

Comment: Option 1 does not do what the user asked for in the original question. The first query only returns rows if `@id = col OR @id is null`. It does not return rows if `@id = 4` but no `col = 4` records exist. The second option may do what the user wants, if the emphasis is on match or not. If there are 250 rows with a 4, but the user always wants 1000 rows, option 2 does not work.

Comment: @LaughingVergil, Right, the first one fails , well if the OP need always 1000 rows then UNION will work. I will add that

Comment: I got it working with the union, but in the end decided to split it up into 2 queries for greater readability. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Obtain non-'col=X' only if 'col=x' not exists:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM table
WHERE col = CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                              FROM table
                              WHERE col = X)
                 THEN X
                 ELSE col
            END
```

Obtain 1000 records, 'col=X' first:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 *
FROM table
ORDER BY CASE WHEN col = X 
              THEN 0
              ELSE 1 END
```

Comment: I think your second option probably returns what the user is looking for, based on the wording of the question. (This, of course, assumes that the number of rows has priority over matching.)